# Unbound Local Error Python Cipher

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying out this Ceasar Cipher and I am getting an error that I can't seem to get around. I am currently using python36 and wondering if there is anyone that can let me know why the unbound local error is coming up. Thank you!

```
#Ceasar Cipher
SYMBOLS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
MAX_KEY_SIZE = len(SYMBOLS)

def getMode():
    while True:
        print('Do you wish to ENCRYPT or DECRYPT a message?')
        mode = input().lower()
        if mode in ['encrypt', 'e', 'decrypt', 'd']:
            return mode
        else:
            print('Enter either "encrypt" or "e" or "decrypt" or "d".')

def getMessage():
    print('Enter your message:')
    return input()

def getKey():
    key = 0
    while True:
        print('Enter the key number (1-%s)' % (MAX_KEY_SIZE))
        key = int(input())
        if (key >= 1 and key <= MAX_KEY_SIZE):
            return key

def getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key):
    if mode[0] == 'd':
        key = -key
    translated = ''

    for symbol in message:
        symbolIndex == SYMBOLS.find(symbol)
        if symbolIndex == -1: # Symbol not found in SYMBOLS.
            # Just add the symbol without any change.
            translated += symbol
        else:
            # Encrypt or decrypt.
            symbolIndex += key

            if symbolIndex >= len(SYMBOLS):
                symbolIndex -= len(SYMBOLS)
            elif symbolIndex < 0:
                symbolIndex += len(SYMBOLS)

            translated += SYMBOLS[symbolIndex]
    return translated

mode = getMode()
message = getMessage()
key = getKey()
print('Your translated text is:')
print(getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key))
```

***Update***
The error I receive looks like this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Badger\Desktop\DEV\Scripts\Ceasar_Cipher.py", line 52, in 
    print(getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key))
  File "C:\Users\Badger\Desktop\DEV\Scripts\Ceasar_Cipher.py", line 32, in getTranslatedMessage
    symbolIndex == SYMBOLS.find(symbol)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'symbolIndex' referenced before assignment

> > > 

Comment: Please edit the post by including actual error log, which helps to solve the problem little quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The key for the Caesar Cipher will be a number from 1 to 26.
your len(SYMBOLS) is larger than 26.
This Code Worked for me with python3

```
MAX_KEY_SIZE = 26

def getMode():
     while True:

         print('Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt a message?')

         mode = raw_input().lower()

         if mode in 'encrypt e decrypt d'.split():

             return mode

         else:

             print('Enter either "encrypt" or "e" or "decrypt" or "d".')



def getMessage():

     print('Enter your message:')

     return raw_input()



def getKey():
     key = 0
     while True:

         print('Enter the key number (1-%s)' % (MAX_KEY_SIZE))

         key = int(input())

         if (key >= 1 and key <= MAX_KEY_SIZE):

             return key



def getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key):

     if mode[0] == 'd':
         key = -key

     translated = ''



     for symbol in message:

         if symbol.isalpha():

             num = ord(symbol)
             num += key



             if symbol.isupper():

                 if num > ord('Z'):

                     num -= 26

                 elif num < ord('A'):

                     num += 26

             elif symbol.islower():

                 if num > ord('z'):

                     num -= 26
                 elif num < ord('a'):

                    num += 26


             translated += chr(num)
         else:

             translated += symbol

     return translated



mode = getMode()

message = getMessage()

key = getKey()
print('Your translated text is:')

print(getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key))
```

Comment: That's awesome. length of the key size i used came from utilizing upper and lowercase letters. Is there any reason that would make a difference if it is specified at the top?

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong...

I set the symbolIndex to "==" when I was assigning it.

After changing it to "=" everything worked beautifully!

Comment: Asterisk_Octothorpe your errors shows that you do right